# Not able to access certain JSON properties in Autoloader

Tags: databricks-autoloader

I have a JSON file that is loaded by two different Autoloaders.
One uses schema evolution and besides replacing spaces in the json property names, writes the json directly to a delta table, and I can see all the values are there properly.
In the second one I am mapping to a defined schema and only use a subset of properties. So use a lot of withColumn and then a select to narrows to my defined column list.

Autoloader definition:

```python
df = (spark
    .readStream
    .format('cloudFiles') 
    .option('cloudFiles.format', 'json') 
    .option('multiLine', 'true') 
    .option('cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode','rescue') 
    .option('cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles','true') 
    .option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation', bronze_schema)
    .option('cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes', 'true')
    .option('pathGlobFilter','*.json')
    .load(upload_path)
    .transform(lambda df: remove_spaces_from_columns(df))
    .withColumn(...
```

Writer:

```python
df.writeStream.format('delta') \
    .queryName(al_stream_name) \
    .outputMode('append') \
    .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_path) \
    .option('mergeSchema', 'true') \
    .trigger(once = True) \
    .table(bronze_table)
```

Issue is that some of the source columns are ok load and I get their values, and others are constantly null in the output table.

For example:

```python
   .withColumn('vl_rating', col('risk_severity.value')) # works
   .withColumn('status',    col('status.name')) # always null
...
   .select(
        'rating',
        'status',
...
```

json is quite simple, these are all string values, they are always populated. The same code works against another simular json file in another autoloader without issue.

I have run out of ideas to fault find on this. My imports are minimal, outside of Autoloader the JSON loads fine.
e.g

```python
%python
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

jsontest = spark.read.option('inferSchema','true').json('dbfs:....json')
df = jsontest.withColumn('status', psf.col('status.name')).select('status')
display(df)
```

Results in the values of the status.name property of the json file

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found generally what is causing this. Interesting cause!

I am scanning a whole directory of json files, and the schema evolves over time (as expected). But when I clear out the autoloader schema and checkpoint directories and only scan the latest json file it all works correctly.

So what I surmise is that something in schema evolution with the older json files causes Autoloader to get into a state where it will not put certain properties into the stream to the writer.

If anyone has any recommendation on how to implement some data quality analysis in an Autoloader I would be most appreciative if you would share.